# Spring REST fetch list of objects from

Tags: java, spring, rest, client

I'm trying to implement a client using Spring Boot which will fetch all products from a site and store them in a database. The storing part is taken care of, but I'm having trouble fetching a list of all the products. 
When testing with Postman, I can get a response with a body like this:

```
<Response>
    <Products>
        <Product Id="221">
            <Name>Screwdriver<Name>
            <Price>5,99</Price>
            <Currency>USD<Currency>
        </Product>
        ...
   </Products>
</Response>
```

I have a Products class with all the fields, getters and setters. Here's what works and outputs the raw body xml:

```
@Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {

        return args -> {
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(resourceUrl, String.class);
            log.info(response.toString());
        };

    }
```

However, I can't seem to get it to fetch all of the individual products from the body. 
Would I be best off using the body fetched here and mapping them to individual Objects, or is there a direct way to do this from the restTemplate?

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you are looking for a way to deserialize your xml string to Java Objects. You have many different options to do it

1. Use JAXB (My personal favorite because of low maintenance), XStream
   or JibX library and let that take care of the conversion for you .
   For this you might need to add certain annotations to your Product
   class (In case of JAXB, you can auto-generate this, if you have
   access to the XSD).
2. Go the painful route- use any of the parsers (depending on your use
   case) DOM, SAX or StaX parser and create Product instances on your
   own.